# AWS SDK - Get metrics for S3 and SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-sdk-net

My question is simple, but I haven't found much by googling myself.

Is there a way to get metrics such as S3 total disk size in a Bucket?

Is there a way to get metrics on amount of emails sent per month using SES?

I am writing an admin tool where I want to track cloud usage basic metrics.

All this of course with the .Net Core AWS SDK.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/event-publishing-retrieving-cloudwatch.html

Comment: And this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/metrics-dimensions.html#s3-cloudwatch-metrics

Comment: Thanks, essentially it's a cloudwatch thing not from the different services directly.